# How does this groovy syntax translate to kotlin?

Tags: groovy, gradle, kotlin

I created a simple Greeting task in Kotlin.

Just like the one in the gradle [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html).

Now I'm adding a simple test to it that looks like this in groovy:

```
class GreetingTaskTest {
    @Test
    public void canAddTaskToProject() {
        Project project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
        def task = project.task('greeting', type: GreetingTask)
        assertTrue(task instanceof GreetingTask)
    }
}
```

I translated this one into Kotlin except one single bit in this line:

```
def task = project.task('greeting', type: GreetingTask)
```

The problematic bit is the second parameter. *type: GreetingTask*

What does it exactly stand for and how does it translate into Kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#task(java.util.Map,%20java.lang.String)). `task` method takes a `String` and a `Map`. *greeting* is an instance of `String` and *type: GreetingTask* is a named parameter which is converted to an instance of `Map`. So you should pass a `Map` as the second arg. Unfortunately, don't know how to declare a `Map` in kotlin. [This](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/map-of.html) method might be helpful.

Comment: Sorry thats not precise enough for me. Also i think its wrong because my example shows the signature with 1st param String 2nd param Closure.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're wrong. See this gist: https://gist.github.com/Opalo/87c196d4f9d434efea39. This is how groovy works. As I said `String` and `Map` variation is used.

Comment: Ah i see. So you can swap params if the types differ. Thanks for pointing me back into the right direction.

Comment: The actual answer working is shown in the other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31455515/3679676.  @opal you could incorporate that here so the accepted answer is complete.

Answer (score 4):

Thx to Opal for leading me to the solution.

In addition to his answer here is the kotlin version of the test:

```
class GreetingTaskTest {
    @Test
    public fun canAddTaskToProject() {
        val project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
        val task = project.task(mapOf("type" to GreetingTask::class.java), "greeting")
        assertTrue(task is GreetingTask)
    }
}
```

Comment: note the `hashMapOf` can just be `mapOf` for a readonly map.  Also note that `javaClass<GreetingTask>()` is no longer correct for Kotlin, that the syntax is now `GreetingTask::class.java`.  Can you please update the answer to be current?